# Question on use of Mayer-Vietoris sequence.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $V$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $x \in V$, prove that $$H_{n-1}(V \setminus \{x \}) \not= 0$$ and that $\mathbb{R}^m$ is not homeomorphicto an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $n \not= m$.

This is an exercise on Mayer-Vietoris sequences, so I am thinking we might apply the sequence to $V$ and $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{ x \}$ but I am not quite sure. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, consider the decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $V$ and $W=\mathbb{R}^n \backslash \{x\}$.  Then the relevant part of the sequence becomes (for $n \geq 2$):

$$ H_n(\mathbb{R}^n) = 0 \to H_{n-1}(V \backslash \{x\}) \to H_{n-1} (V) \oplus H_{n-1}(W) \to H_{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)=0$$

so that $H_{n-1}(V \backslash \{x\}) \cong H_{n-1} (V) \oplus H_{n-1}(W)$.  Note that $\mathbb{R}^n \backslash \{x\}$ deformation retracts onto a sphere $S^{n-1}$ so that $H_{n-1}(W) = \mathbb{Z}$.  In particular, $H_{n-1}(V \backslash \{x \}) \neq 0$.

For the second claim, note that a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^m$ and an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ induces isomorphisms in homology groups.

Comment: I just started reading about this and I am having a hard time to follow your answer. For instance, what is the induced isomorphism in homology groups? Can you fill out the details please.

Comment: Thank your for your answer, after I have read it some times it became more clear. But I still have some questions. 

What do you mean by $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{ x \}$ retracts onto a sphere $S^{n-1}$? I don't understand this part. Also, what conclusion is being drawn by the fact that an homeomorphism induces isomorphism in homology groups?

Comment: Hi Alvin, I have looked closer into your answer and I think I know aha you mean by the deformation retract now. However I still don't know what contradiction you want to achieve by the isomorphism in homology groups. Also, what about the case when $n=1$? Your proof does not seem to cover this case.